# I want to save changes I made on a jframe before I dispose it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a main Jframe class that has the ability to open another jframe. When I dispose() the 2nd frame, return to the main frame, and open the 2nd frame again, changes I made were not saved (like adding buttons, labels, and changes in the backend code too). How do I retain those changes I made?

Comment: Do you have to dispose of the second frame? Can't you hide it?

Comment: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Comment: Sounds like you're using multiple instances of the frame.  You "could" save the state in some way and reload it each time the window is created, but this assumes that you'd never have more then one active instance.  You "could" maintain a single active reference to the second frame after it's created and simply make it visible again.  Which you use would depend on you desired outcomes

Answer (score 0):

JFrame has default close operation HIDE_ON_CLOSE, so leave this default setting and when this second window is necessary set it visible again.

To perform actions that are necessary when JFrame state changes you should implement WindowAdapter:

```
secondFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // actions you want to perform 
    }
});
```